# Create Raster based on extent of shapefile and with resolution of another raster

Tags: qgis, python, raster, r

I have a shapefile in R.

```
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 11.59136 ymin: 50.91873 xmax: 11.65639 ymax: 50.94862
geographic CRS: WGS 84
  id                       geometry
1 NA POLYGON ((11.59136 50.94859..
```

I want to create a raster of the same extent as the shapegile and with a resolution based on the resolution of another raster, namely this one (dem):

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 8067, 9767, 78790389  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 20, 20  (x, y)
extent     : 561762, 757102, 5562496, 5723836  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : /geodata/dem.tif
names      : DEM
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

I tried

```
ras = raster(shp, res = res(dem))
```

but this apparently not the best option...

Comment: So the location you want to set to 1 is some point you can see on this satellite map? I don't get what you mean that it has to be "at a specific location on a particular point of the slope". You can plot the satellite image, use `locator` to click on it, and then set the corresponding pixel at that location to 1 in the raster. Can you do that?

Comment: Sorry, I think this was expressed badly by me. It's not one specific point I can see on a satellite image. I just wanted to see on an optical image where I'm modifying the raster instead of doing this by some sort of indexing. The `locator`-approach sounds perfect  for doing that:) Thank you very much!

Comment: As long as you plot the reference image with base R graphics and its a single plot window then `xy = locator(1, type="p")` will return an X-Y position of a click in the coordinates of the plot.